# SQL get first instance of specific data from a row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

So I have an sql table that looks like this
 [image]

I'm trying to insert a player name into the first instance of Empty with the p1Name, p2Name etc, and also insert it to the `tableNumber` where `tableNumber=minTable` I'm really new to sql so this is probably so wrong, but I'm confused on how to do this.
This is what I tried..

```
sql = "SELECT * as slot FROM Tables "
                                + "WHERE p1Name = 'Empty'" 
                                + " OR p2Name = 'Empty'"
                                + " OR p3Name = 'Empty'"
                                + " OR p4Name = 'Empty'"
                                + " OR p5Name = 'Empty'"
                                + " OR p6Name = 'Empty'"
                                + "AND tableNumber = '" + minTable + "'";
```

It's giving me a sql exception error with no detail so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, if anyone has any insight whatsoever it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question heading and SQL tells you want to retrieve but you are saying you want to insert ? Are you trying to read data or insert ?

Comment: Trying to get something like p1Name back so I can insert it into there at the moment, so if p1Name was "Empty" I would want it to somehow get that column back so I can insert into it

Comment: Can you be more clear?
What you want to insert to tableNumber since it has a value (`tableNumber=minTable`) ?

Comment: I want to find the row the tableNumber=minTable and find the first empty instance of p1Name p2Name or p3Name etc up to p6Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Tables WHERE"
                            + "( p1Name = 'Empty'" 
                            + " OR p2Name = 'Empty'"
                            + " OR p3Name = 'Empty'"
                            + " OR p4Name = 'Empty'"
                            + " OR p5Name = 'Empty'"
                            + " OR p6Name = 'Empty' )"
                            + " AND tableNumber = '" + minTable + "'";
```

Something like this. ' * ' character means "ALL". So the explication is:

> SELECT **ALL DATA** FROM **TABLES** WHERE **(col1='x' OR col2='y' OR ..) AND coln = 'x'**

Comment: I think this is the solution, not 100% sure yet but now I'm getting different errors elsewhere in the code so it's progress :) lol

Comment: in what are you writing this query?